Heat pump not cooling, hard start kit initially fixed for a year, but now problem is back
Its a 3 ton goodman brand new installed in 2022.  In 2023 it stopped cooling just blew warm air.  Reset breakers, it works again.  But then after a day blowing only warm air again.  Then followed a repeatable a vicious cycle of  resetting breakers, cool air for a few hours, then warm air.  I tested the dual/combo cap, it was good.  Someone suggested that I put a hard start kit on it, so I did. and problem went away for a year.
But now again is blowing warm air.  I again  tested the dual/combo cap, its still good.  Removed the hard start kit just for kicks, it worked for a bit but now back to that vicious cycle again.  Hard start is still out of the system.
Should that hard start kit really have been required on a 1 year old compressor unit?
Did my hard start kit die?

I do not know much, but sounds more like a low coolant/freon level or bad/clogged filters.  A hard/soft start kit should only help with starting and not with cooling.

i replace the nordic pure filters every 3 months, and just replaced them last week.  the unit started blowing warm again last night so i shut it all down then this morning tried again.  its been working fine all day, so far.
not sure how long though, until it decides to blow warm air again... how can that be a freon issue?

Low Freon might only provide a few hours of cooling till it cannot keep up.  Something to have a professional check.
